# PHP call to local .NET web service

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services

I'm doing all of this locally for testing purposes right now. I ran the service project in visual studio and have my local version of the site setup to make the call to the web service but it won't hit it.

Here's the call:

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('location' => "https://localhost:51063/Service1.asmx", 'uri' => 'http://localhost:51063/'));
$client->newMeeting(array('id' => '10000', 'location' => 'test', 'committee' => 'test', 'desc' => 'test', 'date' => '2011-08-01', 'duration' => '180', 'agenda' => '', 'notes' => '', 'agenda' => '', 'notes' => ''));
```

And using that I get this error:

```
Uncaught SoapFault
Could not connect to host

Trace in execution order:

Dispatcher→dispatch(null, 'page')  on line 98 in C:\xampp\htdocs\narca\admin\index.php
   Dispatcher→executeAction('plugin', 'committees', array[1])  on line 162 in C:\xampp\htdocs\narca\frog\Framework.php
      PluginController→execute('committees', array[1])  on line 247 in C:\xampp\htdocs\narca\frog\Framework.php
         call_user_func_array(array[2], array[0])  on line 84 in C:\xampp\htdocs\narca\frog\app\controllers\PluginController.php
            CommitteesController→addevent()  on line unknown in unknown
               SoapClient→newMeeting(array[8])  on line 429 in C:\xampp\htdocs\narca\frog\plugins\committees\CommitteesController.php
                  SoapClient→__call('newMeeting', array[1])  on line unknown in unknown
                     SoapClient→__doRequest('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:...', 'https://localhost:51063/Service1.asmx', 'http://localhost:51063/#newMeeting', 1, 0)  on line unknown in unknown
```

If I try to call it like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://localhost:51063/Service1.asmx?WSDL");
```

I get a different error:

```
Uncaught SoapFault
SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://97.67.111.2:51063/Service1.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "http://97.67.111.2:51063/Service1.asmx?WSDL"

Trace in execution order:

Dispatcher→dispatch(null, 'page')  on line 98 in /mnt/stor2-wc1-dfw1/410993/410996/lab.narca.org/web/content/admin/index.php
   Dispatcher→executeAction('plugin', 'committees', array[1])  on line 162 in /mnt/stor2-wc1-dfw1/410993/410996/lab.narca.org/web/content/frog/Framework.php
      PluginController→execute('committees', array[1])  on line 247 in /mnt/stor2-wc1-dfw1/410993/410996/lab.narca.org/web/content/frog/Framework.php
         call_user_func_array(array[2], array[0])  on line 84 in /mnt/stor2-wc1-dfw1/410993/410996/lab.narca.org/web/content/frog/app/controllers/PluginController.php
            CommitteesController→addevent()  on line unknown in unknown
               SoapClient→SoapClient('http://97.67.111.2:51063/Service1.asmx?WSDL')  on line 423 in /mnt/stor2-wc1-dfw1/410993/410996/lab.narca.org/web/content/frog/plugins/committees/CommitteesController.php
```

Is this setup even possible? Or is there a way I can make the live site hit my local service?

Comment: The Visual Studio web server doesn't respond to anything but localhost requests. I don't think that the IP address would work here, so I would check the configuration of your web service.

Comment: have you tried using http:// instead of https:// (with no ssl for testing purposes) ?

Comment: I tried https just before I posted, and had been using http, all with the same results. Could having both apache server and the development server running locally cause problems?

Answer (score 0):

Can you fetch that URL from the server PHP is on, using curl or something similar?  Is there a firewall somewhere that blocks those high-numbered-post requests?  Your PHP looks fine so I don't think you are doing anything wrong there.